# Pausing translate Animation Android ObjectAnimator

Tags: android, animation

Am using an ObjectAnimator to translate the text in a text view similar to a stock ticker. I want to pause the ticker on press of a button. However, inspite of calling cancel()/end() on the animator object, the ticker continues to move till the end of the animation.

Have also tried explicitly clearing all animations on the underlying textView in the AnimatorListerner#onAnimCancel(). However the underlying textView doesn't seem to be associated with any animations.

Would be great if someone could point out as to what would be going wrong.

Relevant sections of code as below.

```
anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mTextViewTicker, "TranslationX", 0, -mSomeValue);
anim.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Animation Pause invoked");
            super.onAnimationCancel(animation);
        }

        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Animation Ended");
            ((View)((ObjectAnimator)animation).getTarget()).setTranslationX(anim.getAnimatedFraction());
        }
    });
anim.start();

public void stopScroll() {
   anim.cancel();
}
```

stopScroll() is invoked from a button click in the activity.